# Как отображать ScroolView в Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть некий Grid, который разделен на n-ое число строк, которое будет меняться при запуске программы или во время выполнения. Высота строк всегда будет одним и тем же числом. При вставке 6 строк с высотой 140px, некоторые элементы будут пропадать с экрана, как отобразить на Grid ScrollView, чтобы можно было просматривать их с помощью скролла?

```
<DockPanel>
        <Grid Height="420" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="420">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Зачем тут вообще сетка?

Comment: Есть контрол `ScrollViewer`, можно поместить `Grid` внутрь этого контрола.